# »Es wird Spaß sein« vs »Es wird Spaß machen«

Tags: verb-usage, verb-choice

I was translating the English phrase:

> It will be fun.

And I translated it as:

> Es wird Spaß sein.

But the answer booklet had it translated as:

> Es wird Spaß machen.

Would the use of *sein* not be appropriate here and why would *machen* be used over *sein*?

Thanks.

Comment: I hope your book had *Spaß*, not *spaß*.

Comment: The German word »Spaß« is a noun, not an adverb. **All** German nouns must **always** be written with an uppercase first letter, so it must be »Spaß« (not »spaß«, this word doesn't exist in German). I edited your question and corrected this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say

> Es wird lustig sein.
> <sup>*It will be funny.*</sup>

Here *lustig* is an adjective in an adverbial usage. It modifies the verb *sein* (to be).

You can use *sein* (to be) also together with a noun:

> Hans wird bald Pensionist sein.
> <sup>*Hans will soon be a pensioner.*</sup>
> Mein Auto wird bald ein Wrack sein.
> <sup>*My car will soon be a wreck.*</sup>

You use this construction to say, that two things are equal (or will become equal if you use future tense) or that one thing is a member of a certain category. But (at least in German) you don't say, that a given action is equal to a fun or belongs to a category named "fun".

Instead, in German you say, that a given action causes (makes) a certain feeling or emotion, and the name of this emotion is "fun" (*Spaß*).

So, *Spaß* is not the action, but its emotional result. And so, an action, that **is** fun in English (i.e. the action belongs to a certain class) **causes** *Spaß* (a feeling/emotion) in German.

So, the correct usage is:

> Es wird Spaß machen.
> <sup>*It will cause a feeling that we call »Spaß«.*</sup>

Comment: Oder "Es wird ein Spaß!" oder "Es wird spaßig."

Comment: Note that *machen* is an example of what is called a "light verb" in English (*Funktionsverb* in German). It combines with several nouns to form fixed phrases which are functionally new verbs. In general these phrases don't translate directly from one language to another, for example "to make fun" means something very different than *Spaß machen*. Also note that *Spaß haben*, *ein Spaß sein* (see the other comment), and *zum Spaß* are possible, but only the first one translates directly to English.